# different colors line chart with react native chart kit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, linechart, react-native-chart-kit

I'm using [react-native-chart-kit](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit) plugin and want to draw a line filled with green and red if goes outside of the blue zone, like in the picture. Can anyone say if it is possible and if so how can I achieve this?

lineChart [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@dorado13/e41f0e)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported yet the possibility to change the color of the line as you want.

What I suggest is to change the color of the dots. That's can be done using the function "getDotColor". That's is supported in last version (6.11.0) for example.

Then you can define your function like this:

```
getDotColor={(dataPoint, dataPointIndex) => {
          if(dataPoint > 70 || dataPoint< 35) 
          return '#ff0000';// red
          else  return '#00ff00';// green
        }}
```

Comment: it works almost fine on short charts and with small data but for me this solution not works (

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in react-native-chart-kit. However, there's another strong charting library- [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts) which can be used to achieve this feature very easily.

The `<LineChart/>` component in *react-native-gifted-charts* accepts a prop named **`highlightedRange`** where you can define a range within which the lines will be rendered differently.
[image]

In the above chart, the portion of the line that lies between 5 and 12 is colored green. This is achieved by using the `highlightedRange` prop-

```
highlightedRange={{
  from: 5,
  to: 12,
  color: 'green',
}}
```

The complete code for the above chart is-

```
import React from 'react';
import {LineChart} from 'react-native-gifted-charts';

const App = () => {
    const data = [
        {value: 6}, {value: 6}, {value: 8}, {value: 5}, {value: 5}, {value: 8}, {value: 0}, {value: 8}, {value: 10}, {value: 10}, {value: 12}, {value: 15}, {value: 20}, {value: 22}, {value: 20}
      ];
    
      return (
        <LineChart
          data={data}
          spacing={22}
          thickness={5}
          color='red'
          hideRules
          hideDataPoints
          xAxisThickness={0}
          yAxisThickness={0}
          highlightedRange={{
            from: 5,
            to: 12,
            color: 'green',
          }}
        />
      );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another chart library, [react-native-statistic-charts](https://github.com/zhiyuang/react-native-statistic-charts). It could accomplish your requirements by setting up a color function. Could refer to this demo:

[image: demo]

```xml
    <Chart
          data={data}
        >
          <Axis
            field="date"
          />
          <Axis field="value" lineStyle={{ strokeWidth: 0 }} tickLineStyle={{ strokeWidth: 0 }} />
          <Line position="date*value" color={{ value: record => ((record['value'] < 1650 && record['value'] > 1626) ? 'green' : 'red') }} />
        </Chart>

        <Line position="date*value"
          color={{ value: record => (
            (record['value'] < 1650 && record['value'] > 1626) ? 'green' : 'red') 
          }}
        />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).